# Shouldn't this Oracle to_number function work?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

I am kind of lost in a problem which should be very trivial. I checked out the related questions, lead to checking the regexp fitting, they do. I have a 4 character long varchar2 and it oracle doesn't want to convert it to numeric.

I checked out this:

```
select 
  nyszamtxt 
  from gyta_megjegyzes 
  where REGEXP_LIKE (nyszamtxt, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

It gives back the expected numbers in varchar2 form, nothing else.

Good then this should work fine I suppose:

```
select 
  to_number(nyszamtxt) 
  from gyta_megjegyzes 
  where REGEXP_LIKE (nyszamtxt, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
```

No, it says ORA 01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"

Am I missing something really trivial? I can't tell what is the problem.

Comment: just null values, but it shouldn't be in the select because of regexp_like

Comment: What your first query giving output.its giving null values

Comment: There's some non numeric character, can you see the `ASCII` values in it, using `DUMP(nyszamtxt)`

Comment: Whoever will have this problem: your Varchar2 might contain some invisible mines like "End of line" or simply non-digit characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a general basis, Oracle won't just strip non numeric characters, as in `abc1234xyz`. You probably want to do one of these:

- Harden your expression:

  ```
  where REGEXP_LIKE (nyszamtxt, '^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$');
  ```
- Strip characters yourself:

  ```
  select 
  to_number(REGEXP_REPLACE(nyszamtxt, '[^0-9]+', '')) 
  from gyta_megjegyzes 
  where REGEXP_LIKE (nyszamtxt, '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]');
  ```

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why, all the varchar2s were like '1256' I don't see anything needed to stripped.

Comment: Strange. Either way, your query would be safer stripping out non-numeric characters as in the answer. Are you totally sure your original query was not returning any non-numeric characters?

Comment: Thanks a lot! my original update is working as well, I am still curious why does oracle need to strip the varchar2 fields when it is obviously have only 4 digits in there without any garbage. I will mark your answer correct when it the option is available.

Comment: @Drumbeg, I triplechecked, I suspected an "l" instead of "1" somewhere and these kind of stuff, simply nothing. NOW I checked the result, an End of line was there!